# ¿Que esta mal en esta petición AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buen Dia tengo el siguiente problema al momento de ralizar una peticion por ajax no pasa nada , pero cuando tiene un dato esa llamada si lo pasa al vb:

Creo yo que es error de sintaxis:

```
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Opciones.aspx/SubirArchivo",
                    data: "{S3_Arn:'" + s3_arn_of_file + ',' + "'Rds_file: " + rds_file_path + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                   
                });
```

y este Es mi Vb :

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function SubirArchivo(ByVal S3_Arn As String, ByVal Rds_file As String) As String
        Dim cls As New NetUtilities2005.clsUtilities
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Try

            cls.AddParameter("@s3_arn_of_file", S3_Arn)

            cls.AddParameter("@overwrite_file", 1)
            dt = cls.List("msdb.dbo.rds_download_from_s3 ").ToTable

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)

    End Function
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar ,Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola data estas poniendo todo entre comillas

```
data: "{S3_Arn:'" + s3_arn_of_file + ',' + "'Rds_file: " + rds_file_path + "}"
```

y es

```
data: {S3_Arn: s3_arn_of_file, Rds_file: rds_file_path}
```

Te paso un ejemplo de un programa que estoy haciendo

```
$.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("BuscarInstructor")',
                 data: {
                     instructorId: instructorId,
                     objetoId: objetoID
                 },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',

                 success: function (json) {
                     CargarFormulario(json.instructor);
                     CargarAdjuntos(json.instructor.adjuntos);
                     FormularioUtil.Deshabilitar($("#FormInstructor"), false);
                     $("#InstructorId").prop("disabled", true);
                },

                 error: function (xhr, status) {
                     MensajeUtil.Error(xhr.responseJSON.error);
                },

                 complete: function (xhr, status) {
                     CloseLoader();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hola @JorgeLuis , ya  utilice tu respuesta pero aun así no salta hacia el vb ,no se que podría ser ,lo curioso es que solo funciona con un parámetro y ya con dos no funciona. Gracias por comentar

Comment: Hola puedes probar {S3_Arn:"1", Rds_file:  "2"} a ver si funciona

Comment: Si funciona :) , una duda como podría hacerlo con variables

Comment: Checa que te mandan tus variables s3_arn_of_file y Rds_file tal vez alguna te manda algo raro o no existen

Comment: talvez sea eso porque lo que contiene son Directorios que contienen '/' y '-'

Comment: No, ya intente poniendo esos caracteres y si funciona, lo que yo creo que alguna de tus variables esta regresando algo raro, antes del ajax pon alert(s3_arn_of_file) y alert(rds_file_path) para ver si es el valor que quieres

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo como tu dijiste al principio solo que le agregue JSON.stringify y ya funciono

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meter data en una variable y despues solo mandas a llamar la variable en el data:

```
parametros = {
        'direccion': direccion, //direccion es una variable
        'accion': "buscar", //buscar es un texto normal
        'cliente': params //params es una variable
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros, //aqui mandas a llamar la vairable parametros
        url: "emb_bus_dir.php",
        type: "post",
        beforeSend: function(response) {
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#div_dir_bus").html(response);
        }

    });
```